# solr 4.4 multiple datasource connection

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

in my db-data-config.xml i have configured two datasource, each with his parameter name,
for example:

```
<dataSource name="test1"
     type="JdbcDataSource"
     driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/firstdb"
     user="username1"
     password="psw1"/>

<dataSource name="test2"
     type="JdbcDataSource"
     driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/seconddb"
     user="username2"
     password="psw2"/>

<document name="content">
        <entity name="news" datasource="test1" query="select...">
        <field column="OTYPE_ID" name="otypeID" />
            <field column="NWS_ID" name="cntID" />
            ....
        </entity>

        <entity name="news_update" datasource="test2" query="select...">
        <field column="OTYPE_ID" name="otypeID" />
            <field column="NWS_ID" name="cntID" />
            ....
        </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

but when in solr from dataimport i execute the second entity-name-query it launch an exception:

"*Table 'firstdb.secondTable' doesn't exist\n\tat*"
could someone help me? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

A think that your query for news_update is wrong. You must have an error on name of table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this question showed up on the solr-user mailing list.  The answer given there was that you are using datasource in your entity tags instead of dataSource.  It's case sensitive.  If I recall the thread correctly, changing this solved your problem.